# Meteor pure clients apps

Tags: meteor

It's possible to create Meteor app without the need for a server (run it as pure APK)? I have some projects in mind and I don't need database.

Comment: why would you want to use Meteor in that case? Also define *pure APK*

Comment: Not dependant on server